# Unable to access Flash global settings

Tags: flash

When I try to use a Flash application, it gives me the dialog asking for more local storage. When I tried to use the Global settings as suggested here and in numerous other places, it tells me "This content requires Flash", which I already have. What is going on?

EDIT: I have taken the following screenshot which shows the problem
[image: Screenshot showing the problem]

Answer (score 0):

i think you haven't installed flash player,
for this install `synaptic` by typing

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

in the terminal and open the synaptic by typing

```
sudo synaptic
```

search for the `flashplugin-installer` in synaptic and mark it for installation and click apply, then it will work.

Comment: I am still getting the same error.